# Why is the struct-like constructor removed when I define virtual function?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions

Suppose I define the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};
```

Now I can initialize it like a struct:

```
A a { .x = 1; }
```

However, when I define any *virtual* function, the constructor goes away:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    virtual int f() {}
};

A a { .x = 1; }
```

The message is:

```
# error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

Why does a virtual function delete that constructor?

Comment: That initialization isn't C++. Anyway, I think you mean brace enclosed initialization, so I closed as duplicate. If you mean something else let me know and I'll consider re-opening.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's a GCC extension and not the same thing as the question you linked.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious RIght, so not C++. In which case the answer should be in the gcc documentation. As I said earlier, I am happy to re-open this if necessary.

Comment: Wrongly closed as dup. Too many questions are closed as dup that aren't dup.